# Params to objective-c singleton from swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, parameters, singleton

So I have an objective-c singleton that I am calling from swift. The project has a Bridging-Header and calling the printValue: method with an explicit value works fine:

```
SingletonTester.sharedInstance().printValue(64)         // works fine
```

But - parameterizing this call gives me an error:
`let note = 64
SingletonTester.sharedInstance().printValue(note)       // doesn’t compile`

*Error: ViewController.swift:21:46: Cannot call value of non-function type '((UInt) -> Void)!'*

Real noob issue, but it’s got me flustered.

TIA

Comment: What does the method signature of `printValue` look like?

Comment: Here it is:
 
`- (void)printValue:(NSUInteger)value {
 NSLog(@"print value:%ld", value);
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your value is the wrong type. The printValue function is expecting a UInt, but when you say `let note = 64`, the compiler assumes Int by default. You can do this:

```
let note: UInt = 64
SingletonTest.sharedInstance().printValue(note)
```

Or this:

```
let note = 64
SingletonTest.sharedInstance().printValue(UInt(note))
```

Comment: That works! Still have to learn to decode these errors and to always explicitly cast my variables.

Comment: Seems like the error message you got was particularly unhelpful. Usually it would tell you the specific types that didn't match.